# R replace last nth value with NA by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace value(s) with NA by group.

```
have <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

want1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                    value = c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA))

want2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                    value = c(1,2,NA,NA,5,NA,NA))
```

want1 corresponds to replacing the last obs of value with NA and want2 corresponds to replacing last obs of value & last 2nd value with NA. I'm currently trying to do with with dplyr package but can't seem to get any traction. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `row_number()` to test the current row against `n()` the total rows in the group.

```
have |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(
    last1 = ifelse(row_number() == n(), NA, value),
    last2 = ifelse(row_number() >= n() - 1, NA, value)
  )
# # A tibble: 7 × 4
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id value last1 last2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     2     2
# 3     1     3     3    NA
# 4     1     4    NA    NA
# 5     2     5     5     5
# 6     2     6     6    NA
# 7     2     7    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

And a general way to provide variants as different data frames.

```
lapply(
  1:2,
  function(k) {
    have %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(value=ifelse(row_number() <= (n() - k), value, NA))
  }
)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 7 × 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     1    NA
5     2     5
6     2     6
7     2    NA

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 × 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1    NA
4     1    NA
5     2     5
6     2    NA
7     2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way.

```r
have <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

want1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                    value = c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA))

want2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                    value = c(1,2,NA,NA,5,NA,NA))

with(have, ave(value, id, FUN = \(x){
  x[length(x)] <- NA
  x
}))
#> [1]  1  2  3 NA  5  6 NA
with(have, ave(value, id, FUN = \(x){
  x[length(x)] <- NA
  if(length(x) > 1)
    x[length(x) - 1L] <- NA
  x
}))
#> [1]  1  2 NA NA  5 NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Then reassign these results to column `value`.